# Why typescript occurs compile error with using the surrounded constant condition?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm always curious about when the union-type condition handling in Typescript with React-native is used, If I used `const` with surrounding conditions, Typescript does not detect the inner condition of `const`. It must exist within the same scope for it to work.

Why it occurs compile error?

example

```
  import {isNull} from 'lodash';

  ...,

  const scrollViewRef = useRef<ScrollView | null>(null)

  const onPressFooter = useCallback(() => {
    if (isNull(scrollViewRef)) return; --> b line show compile error
    if (scrollViewRef === null) return; --> b line not occurs error 

    scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({y :0, animated : true}) // -> b
  }, [])
```

Comment: you should include the text of the compile error

Comment: Oh sorry. 
Error log this !

``(property) React.MutableRefObject<ScrollView | null>.current: ScrollView | null
Object is possibly 'null'.``

Answer (score 0):

useRef is object type value, which have properties by default. So your generic types <ScrollView | null> is used to type scrollViewRef.current property.Can you try to change your null check condition to this?

```
if (isNull(scrollViewRef.current)) return;
```

Comment: Oh my god...Thank you for your time. I solved this problem thanks to your answer.